# "The type or namespace name '[Type]' is not valid in this scope" Error in visual studio Watch Window?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, ide, code-contracts

I was having trouble in `Watch Window` when I try to watch any type, I keep getting error **"The type or namespace name '[Type]' is not valid in this scope"**. I had to give the full namespace along with the type in the watch window to fix this error.

This is just an example it happens for any type -

If I add a watch like `new Uri(Location)`  watch window shows the error. So I should include the namespace `new System.Uri(Location)` for it to work. This was more of an annoyance.

Found this [**Link**](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9e8cec67-402f-4ac6-87be-204f2441f9f0/why-is-type-resolution-not-working-in-my-watch-windows?forum=vsdebug) where it was found Code contracts setting for the project causes this issue. After Disabling runtime contract checking for the code contract, the Watch/Quick Watch works as expected.

> Project Properties-> Code Contracts-> Disable Perform Runtime Contract
>   Checking

What is wrong in enabling run time contract checking for code contracts? Is there any problem with Code Contract setup? or something to do with the project setting? or a bug in Visual Studio?

Comment: I had the same behaviour with Code Contracts with when using the Immediate Window in Visual Studio 2010, 2012 and 2013. I don't get it with Visual Studio 2015. So I would attribute it to a bug in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a correctly spelled "using" statement for the namespace. If you've written the using statement only for a particular block, you have to implicitly declare the namespace when debugging or even coding out of that block to access the the namespace.

Comment: Sadly, that's not the problem. If `using` was not there then it will be a compile time error. This is not the case, everything works well with code contracts disabled with no code change done. Watch window only exhibits the problem, my guess is it has to do with code contracts/resharper installation is hindering the watch.